# Is there way to Split left and right channels from audio in dart/flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, audio, streaming

I want to split the audio/music(stereo) format file into different channels i.e Left and right audio channel in the flutter and stream/play them differently;

Comment: Flutter does not handle audio. This is up to whatever audio package you use. Last option would be to fork or create your own audio package and add desired functionality.